# Rails3: Prefix to all url_for URLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, url-routing

I add i18n to my webpage (different content for different languages). My URLs look loke this:

```
http://host.tld/de/news/15
http://host.tld/en/news/15
...
```

All my URLs in the application are set by the `link_to`/`url_for` method like this

```
url_for("/news/#{news.id}/#{urlify(news.title)}")
url_for("/news/#{@news.section}")
...
```

My routing looks like this:

```
scope "/:language/", :language => /de|en/ do
  match "news/:news_id(/:title)" => "news#show_entry", :constraints => { :news_id => /[0-9]+/ }
  ...
end
```

I add this to my ApplicationController:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  {:language => I18n.locale}
end
```

Now I want to add the language prefix to ALL the URLs without change all the url_for()-calls. Is there a solution (parameter/config-option or something) to add this prefix? It should work with relative paths, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking not to change all the url for calls you could add a method in the application_helper.rb file to override the existing methods to add in the language

```
def url_for(options={})
  if options[:language]
    '/options[:language]' + super
  else
    super
  end
end

def link_tolink_to(*args, &block)
  options = args[1] || {}
  if options[:language]
    '/options[:language]' + super
  else
    super
  end
end
```